# List Box Multiple Selection Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello Friends I am using a list box control in aspx page
i have set multiple selection property to true, but when i try to select more than one item
it does not select multiple items, it selects one only do i have to do something programatically here is my code

```
<html>

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
         <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"
 SelectionMode="Multiple">
         <asp:ListItem Text="hi" Value="hi"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="hi" Value="hi"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="hi" Value="hi"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="hi" Value="hi"></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:ListBox>
     </div>
     </form>
</html>
```

on code behind nothing ...i want why it is not selecting more than one item's ..
 i am using namespace using System.Web.UI.WebControls; as well but of no avail..

Comment: Is it the client-side behaviour that seems wrong to you? Are you holding down the Ctrl key to make your multiple selections? Or is it the postback, server-side behaviour that seems wrong?

Comment: Even if by holding shift or ctr key i do multiple selection it does not print multiple selected item when i tried it using code behind code.. it always print first item only..
i write code behind

Comment: <html>
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            string msg = "";
            if (li.Selected == true)
            {
                msg += "<BR>" + li.Text + " is selected.";
                Response.Write(msg);
           }
        }
        
    }
}
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the doc link with examples of use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx

To select multiple items in your dropdown, ensure you use the ctrl key and click the items you want. You may need to change the size of the dropdown (so that it shows more than one item at a time) to see this more easily.

I'd start with the second example on the link as that is an example of what you are trying to do (usage wise).

Comment: public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
        foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            string msg = "";
            if (li.Selected == true)
            {
                msg += "<BR>" + li.Text + " is selected.";
                Response.Write(msg);
            }
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: the abve code behind code do not pringt all selected items on button click instead it prints first item always..

Comment: how are you selecting multiple items in the page? Also, have you turned on trace mode?

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new
      StringBuilder();
                  foreach (ListItem li in branch.Items)
                  {
      
                      if (li.Selected == true)
                      {
                          sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value)
      +", ");
                      }
                  }
     li is integer value of my check box list which are getting generated

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the 'FindByValue' method of ListBox

```
foreach (string selectedValue in SelectedValuesArray)
                    {
                        lstBranch.Items.FindByValue(selectedValue).Selected = true;
                    }
```